# How can I get changes of a Spinner?

Tags: android, database, spinner

I am working on an app, which has a spinner in two activities. In the first activity the user can edit the spinner item and save the value. I used an `ArrayAdapter` and a `onItemSelectedListener` to store the value in the database. This works fine.

In the second activity the spinner with the changes of the user should be shown. Can anybody tell me how to solve this problem? If you need some more information, please ask, because I am a newbie on android.

This is the code for the first activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle icicle) {
super.onCreate(icicle);
setContentView(R.layout.my_spinner1);

final Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sp_countries);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.countries,
R.layout.spinner1);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);

spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 
{
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View childView, int position, long id) 
{
mSave.countries = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
}
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) 
{
}
});
```

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you get the value from the updated database and set the whole values through setAdapter()
method in the spinner or notify the spinner to change something in database.